# How to find height of a HTML element in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, headless-browser

I am stuck with quite a tricky issue for a couple of days now. I have a auto-generated HTML page in a variable as string in `node.js`. I need to find the height of some HTML elements and do HTML manipulations (like tag creation, deletion, append, css attribute setting etc).

Obviously I need to make a DOM like structure of my HTML page first and then proceed.

While for the HTML manipulations I have many options like `cheerio`, `node.io`, `jsdom` etc but none of these allow me to find the height of the element at the node.

So after wasting quite a lot of time on it, I have decided to look for heavier solutions, something like implementing a headless browser (`phantomjs` etc.) at the node and drive an elements `offsetHeight` through plain javascript.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to reach my objective like this? What headless browser will be best suited for this task?

If i am going in the wrong direction, then can anyone suggest me any other working solution?

At this point I am ready to try anything.

Thnx in advance!!

Note: Using `javascript` at the client side has many problems in my particular case because the contents of the generated HTML page are supposed to be used by the client to paste in his website. Leaving a running `javascript` that re-structures the HTML will make it difficult at his end.

Comment: It sounds like you're heading down a dead-end path; the real question is why do you think you need to get the height of an element on the server? I suspect answering that question will lead you to a solution not involving doing that. The height of an element has no meaning in the absense of a display. So while you *can* use a headless browser for this, you'd have to tell the browser what size window to emulate, and that makes the answer specific to that window size, which isn't really any better than just picking your own answer out of the air.

Comment: Many html set their width and heigth at render time, when the browser defines it box model. I don't think you can get it on server

Comment: this is not to mention CSS and cross browser differences

Comment: Agree with @T.J.Crowder. You should probably introduce some JavaScript in your HTML string, which gets executed on the browser, and can figure out the actual height of the element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its true that height of an element has no meaning in the absence of a display but i need the height to prepare my auto-generated HTML for the display at the client-side. I already have a client-side javascript for my needs but due to the resource inefficiency and "uncleanliness" (my boss came up with this word) of the page i need to migrate it to server-side. Height of the elements is the last thing i need for complete migration.

Comment: @Carlos487 Fortunately, the elements in question already have their widths and content defined so it wouldn't matter in most of the cases what screen size i am rendering for (it would matter on smaller screens, like smartphone screens, when the element is squeezed beyond its min-width but i think i can take care of it)

Comment: @numbers1311407 and shreyas what I am not sure about is whether even headless browsers will be able to provide me with `offsetHeight`...

Comment: If your boss thinks calculating height of a styled DOM element client-side is unclean, attempting to calculate it server-side is so caked in filth as to be unrecognizable.  Tell your boss he's wrong and find a different path.

Comment: @numbers1311407 actually i kind of agree with him.. hehehe...The contents of the auto-generated HTML page is supposed to be used by the client to paste it in his page, so leaving a running javascript will be messy on his end.

Answer (score 3):

Node's server-side HTML libraries (like cheerio and jsdom) are strictly DOM API emulation libraries. They do not attempt to actually render a document, which is necessary to compute element size and position.

If you *really* need to calculate the size of an element on the server, you need a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).  It is a full WebKit renderer with a JavaScript API.  It is entirely separate from node, so you either need to write a utility script using [Phantom's API](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference), or use [a npm module that lets you control Phantom from node](https://npmjs.org/package/phantom-proxy).

---

After reading the comments under your question, it is pretty clear that you should not be calculating heights on the server.  Client-side code is the proper place to do it.

Comment: what about zombie? i heard its lighter and faster than phantomjs plus it comes as a node module.

Comment: @SurenderThakran: zombie is not a real browser rendering engine.  It is a DOM + Browser API emulator -- it's basically jsdom plus extra API implementations on top.  I've not actually tried it, but I highly doubt if it will give you accurate sizing.